# Parse date in bootstrap date range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, parsing

In the bootstrap daterange picker i access the date by below code.

```
var startDate = $('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate._d;
```

and if i print in the console it looks like

```
"Mon Jan 10 2013 01:00:00 GMT +0600"
```

Is it possible to change this date format into like below:
     2013-01-10 01:00:00

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to format the Date in javascript: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below one works perfectly fine.

```
var start = moment(start_date).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Hope it helps to anyone

Answer (score 1):

u can try it

```
var startDate = $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss'
        }
    });
```

and this link help u 
http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples

Comment: I tried it shows as an Object and no value is showing

Answer (score 0):

this will worked fine for your date format.
You can also change last *.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");*

```
$('#reportrange').data('daterangepicker').startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```